# Regex decimal to int

Tags: c#, regex

Im trying to read a decimal number from textbox and convert it in int to calculate with it.

The string looks like this +0.003_mm.
Based on the regex online tools my pattern to capture the decimal number should look like this "d*(\d+.\d+" and the result would be 0.003

While testing this im was trying to display the 0.003 in a textbox called "mtw_textbox" thats why i convert it to a string in the end.

I have tried it this way and also as an Int32 for "mittelwert1" but i am getting an error saying that is the wrong format for " Int mittelwert1 = Convert.ToInt32(mtw1.Value);"

What am i doing wrong ?

```
       private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"d*(\d+\.\d+)");
        Match mtw1 = regex.Match(mw1_textbox.Text);

        if (mtw1.Success) { 
        Int mittelwert1 = Convert.ToInt32(mtw1.Value);
        string testen = mittelwert1.ToString();
```

Comment: "0.003" is not an integer (but a decimal, float or double)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting "0.003" to integer will throw exactly this exception. This is beacause 0.003 is not an integer. Try converting to any floating point number, like float, double or decimal:

```
double mittelwert1 = Convert.ToDouble(mtw1.Value);
```

Comment: Whops thanks now it is working that was kinda stupid from me. Didnt think of that at haha

Comment: hm that Problem is fixed now but it isnt right yet. I dont get the comma right. For example on 0.003 it shows me only the 3. 
On a number like 1,03 it says 103. The test websites showed me the comma with the caption so that should be right ? Does the comma get lost during the converting?

Comment: You probably have an issue with localization - try adding current culture = invariantCulture param to conversion (in some cultures, decimal separator is not a dot). If it doesnt help, feel free to post it as another question on SO :)